How to cut an irregular shape out of a mesh while preserving its topology?
I need to cut an irregular shape out of a mesh while preserving the mesh's topology.

Let's imagine that the red shape has a very high number of vertices, while my mesh is low poly.
How I approached it and failed
I modeled the irregular shape I needed, extruded it outward, and used a Boolean modifier to subtract it from the grid. Unfortunately, this resulted in a lot of n-gons along the edges.
What I need are just the vertices at the intersection of the existing edges (the yellow dots) so I can create the green-highlighted mesh.
Of course, I understand that the edges will be sharper, as I indicated with the blue line.

What happens if you just make the contour (from editing a circle with an even number of verttices) and use "grid fill"? (Ctrl+F)

You can use exact technique with booleans and when you get the result with a lot of n-gons like this:

just double  Alt  + click the outer edge to select it all and use Limited Dissolve(Mesh -> Clean Up -> Limited Dissolve) with a high Max Angle:


Provided you have done the boolean intersection from extruded grid and shape, you can take the 2d bottom and treat the ngons like this:

Where:

"Extrude shape" makes a solid from the weird contour (bottom of the solid at z=0)
"Solidify" makes a solid from the grid (starting below z=0 and ending above)
Get 2d bottom takes only the points at z=0

Treatment logic:

Points that are connected to a single face are not "grid points", select these to set their position
Sets their position to the same position as the next point in the face.
Merges

This treatment logic works well if the shape and the grid have similar point spacing. If they're different, you need the repeat zone to interactively merge points (because there is more than one point that don't belong to the grid and it's sort of difficult to find the position it should go other than "next point")
PS: some sharp edges may be removed by this treatment, if they're desired, you can improve the selection either by:

Reducing the number of iterations in the repeat (min 1)
Change the "selection" to "point has only one face" AND "face has more than 4 points". (You can use the "face of corner" and "corners of face" nodes for that)


Results:

File:

